# Remove N lines to keep only 250 lines in a variable bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am devlopping a little bash script that permits me to extract lines from a log file.
Actually i want to print only 250 lines at the end, but i don't want to select how much i exactly need to remove.

So it means i have this `output = $(tail -n1000 $filename | grep -v "RCON")`

But in case it's more than 250 lines it cuts every "first lines" is there a way to do this witout knowing exactly the n lines ? I mean an easier way than do an if and a while just for it.

Comment: Not clear, could you please post sample of input and expected output in your question and let us know then?

Comment: `tail -n1000 $filename | grep -v "RCON" | tail -n250` would give you the last 250 lines that satisfied your `tail -n1000 $filename | grep -v "RCON"` query.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks exactly what i wanted !

Comment: @Poli : Though a slightly different from what you exactly asked, I would consider a `nl -na| $filename|grep -VF RCON|tail -n 250`. This gives you the last 250 lines not containing _RCON_, plus the line numbers into the original file, in case you need to locate a logging event for closer investigation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your description is a  bit unclear. Here are some ideas that might help you:

```
# Print (max) 250 lines that don't contain RCON
grep -m250 -v RCON file

# Print (max) 250 lines that don't contain RCON (from the end)
tac file | grep -m250 -v RCON | tac

# Print all lines that don't contain RCON only considering the first 250 lines
head -n250 file | grep -v RCON

# Print all lines that don't contain RCON only considering the last 250 lines
tail -n250 file | grep -v RCON
```

So you can create your own specific solution using these building blocks:

```
head -nx         # consider first x lines from file or stdin
tail -nx         # consider last x lines from file or stdin
grep -mx         # select max. x matches
tac | ... | tac  # read file from end (better performance for big files)
```